# Counting the number of objects in an array with recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have some problems with recursion and to understand it I'm trying to make up questions for myself and solve them. This particular question has gotten me confused:
consider this as an input in the form of a string:

```
[[a,b,c],[[d]],[[e,f]],[g],h,i,[[j,[k,l]]]]
```

the goal is to find the total number of things in the lists and the lists them self.for this example the result would be:`12`+`10` = `22`
note that the input is not an array,it is a string.Also instead of `a`,`b`,...
anything can be used,like numbers,strings etc.

```
[12345,0.34,["afv",24]]
```

This is my idea but I will mention why I cant implement it:
We write a function that starts iterating the string.It should count the total thing between `[` and `]`.whenever the function reaches a `[` it will recall itself to iterate through the remaining string.This way it can go deeper into the arrays.
These are my problems:

1. I don't know whether my idea is correct or not.
2. If my idea is correct,what is the base case.
3. How can I make sure that it counts all the things inside regardless of in what are they?(I mean how can I make sure it treats numbers,strings etc the same)
4. I think the body of the function should look like this(I'm using java here but I don't think the language is very important here):

   `public static int counter(String a){
               int sum = 0;
               //some code to iterate the string
               //some code to check the conditions and if needed call the method 
               //some code to add the number of objects and arrays to sum
               return sum;
              }`

If the code should like what I said then how can I fill the body?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Don't try to do all at the same time. This will lead to very complex code and you will likely got lost. The first step would be to parse the input into an abstract syntax tree that reflects the structure and then do the counting.

Comment: @Henry sorry but I'm a little amateur ,can you explain with more details?tnx

Comment: Your basic idea is correct. It's called a 'recursive descent parser' and it's a well-known algorithm.

Comment: @IanMercer yes,some one tolled me the name and I searched for it.but I have a hard time actually doing the code

Comment: Although if you really don't care about what's inside, and you are sure the input is well-formed, you could probably just have a simple state machine. STATE 1 = Normal. State 2 = IN A THING, State 3 = IN A QUOTED THING. Read each character, depending on state handle count, change state as necessary, ... Look up "Finite State Machine".

Answer (score 1):

Depending how you design your recursive algorithm and size of input, you may run into the common problem of **recursive stack overflow**, where you have very deep recursion and run out of memory space

This is a different iterative pythonic solution if you do **not** have to use recursion but you should be able to transpose this to Java.

You want to increment you count for every item that is separated by commas. However, if that element has ']' characters, you know that it is a part of a embedded list. By counting the closing braces and the element, you can get the total.

**Updated** to handle strings with embedded commas

```
# Function for removing the chars between apostrophes
def remove(s,c):
    while(s.find(c) != -1):
        i = s.find(c) # find the first instance of c but ' or " in our case
        i2 = s.find(c,i+1) # find the second instance
        s = s[0:i]+s[i2+1:] # Remove the string
        return s
    return s

s = "[['a,b,c'],[1,2,3]]"
s = s[:-1] # remove the last list char
total = 0
s = remove(s,'\'')
s = remove(s,'"')
l = s.split(',')
for el in l:
    total+=1
    total+= el.count(']')
print(total)
```

Comment: This may be too simplistic, consider cases like `["a,b,c"]`.

Comment: Note: This does not cover the case where the elements may be embedded strings with commas such as "hello,there"

Comment: @Jae Yang tnx for the solution but I want to know the solution with recursion.also you have to use regx in java to split a string,it is also possible to this with an algorithm but if the string is for instance 10000 charters long,I don't think it would be very time efficient to split the string and put it into an array or list.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't care about parsing the actual contents of the lists (for that you would implement a recursive descent parser), you can instead implement a simple state machine.

Here's a **very rough**, **partial** implementation in pseudo code just to give you some idea about how you might implement this. Ideally you would have more states to detect syntax errors:

```
int lists, elements = 0;
state = normal;
foreach (char c in input)
{
   switch state
      case normal:
        if (c == '[')
          lists++;
        else if (c == ']')
          // do nothing
        else if (c == ',')
          // do nothing (will only count [ and , on elements)
        else if (c == '"')
          elements++;
          state = quoted_element
        else
          elements++;
          state = element; 
        break;

      case quoted_element:
        if (c == '"')
          state = element;
        break;

      case element:
        if (c == '"' || c == '[')
          exception("Syntax error");
        else if (c == ",")
          elements++;
        else if (c == "]")
          state = normal;
        break;
}
```

Comment: How is that recursive?

Comment: It's not; see comments on question. If you want recursion make a recursive descent parser, but for the stated goal you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursion in JavaScript that might give you some ideas.

```js
function f(s){
  function nextIndexafterStr(i){
    while (!(s[i] == "\"" && s[i-1] != "\\"))
      i++;
    return i + 1;
  }

  function nextIndexafterNum(i){
    while (![",", "]"].includes(s[i]))
      i++;
    return i;
  }

  // Returns [numArrays, numElements, endIndex]
  // Assumes valid input
  function g(i, as, es){
    // base case
    if (s[i] == "]" || i == s.length)
      return [as, es, i];

    if (s[i] == ",")
      return g(i + 1, as, es);

    // a list
    if (s[i] == "["){
      const [aas, ees, endIndex] = g(i + 1, 0, 0);
      return g(endIndex + 1, as + 1 + aas, es + ees);
    }

    // string element
    if (s[i] == "\"")
      return g(nextIndexafterStr(i + 1), as, es + 1);

    // number or variable-name element
    return g(nextIndexafterNum(i), as, es + 1);
  }

  const [as, es, _] = g(0, 0, 0);
  return as + es;
}


var a = [12345,0.34,["af\"v",24]];
var b = "[[a,b,c],[[d]],[[e,f]],[g],h,i,[[j,[k,l]]]]";

a = JSON.stringify(a);
console.log(a);
console.log(f(a));
console.log(b);
console.log(f(b));
```